# ejabberd BOSH takes too many minutes in HTTP pre-bind

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

**The context:**

I'm trying to generate a session from my back-end to attach to it from my front-end. In the process, I'm sending the request to ejabberd, to the mod_http_bind module listening on the port 5280, as is explained in [metajack.im post](http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/).

Session id requests are sent using [this script](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs/blob/master/examples/attach/boshclient.py).

I'm using external authentication and is working well, in a normal time, when connecting directly through XMPP or WebAdmin.

**The problem**:

It's generating the session id right BUT it's taking around 1-3 minutes. After this time my Bosh chat client through a timeout. Beside this, it's too much time for a simple session id.

Any suggestion??

**Extra info:**

Here is my ejabberd logs:

*ejabberd-log*

```
2015-12-14 15:52:34.655 [info] <0.490.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.3971>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:49840 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2015-12-14 15:52:34.655 [info] <0.713.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3971>}
2015-12-14 15:53:43.187 [info] <0.490.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.3972>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:49855 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2015-12-14 15:53:43.187 [info] <0.715.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3972>}
```

*error.log*

```
--empty--
```

*crash.log*

```
--empty--
```

Ejabberd version:

15.11

*ejabberd.log with log_level at debug*

```
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [info] <0.1240.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.7839>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:50027 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http:init:153 S: [{[<<"register">>],mod_register_web},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind}]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [info] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.7839>}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:280 (#Port<0.7839>) http query: 'POST' <<"/http-bind">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http:extract_path_query:392 client data: <<"<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' to='chatdomain' window='5' xml:lang='en' rid='1598394' hold='1' wait='70'/>">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http:process:350 [<<"http-bind">>] matches [<<"http-bind">>]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.170 [debug] <0.1241.0>@mod_http_bind:process:68 Incoming data: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' to='chatdomain' window='5' xml:lang='en' rid='1598394' hold='1' wait='70'/>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.171 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:parse_request:1114 --- incoming data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' to='chatdomain' window='5' xml:lang='en' rid='1598394' hold='1' wait='70'/>
 --- END --- 
2015-12-14 16:20:19.171 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:start:154 Starting session
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:init:339 started: {<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50027}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_session_start:282 got pid: <0.1242.0>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_session_start:321 Create session: <<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:775 Looking for session: <<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:442 New request: {http_put,1598394,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"to">>,<<"chatdomain">>},{<<"window">>,<<"5">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598394">>},{<<"hold">>,<<"1">>},{<<"wait">>,<<"70">>}],[],155,1,{<<"chatdomain">>,<<>>},{{127,0,0,1},50027}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:558 New request: {http_put,1598394,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"to">>,<<"chatdomain">>},{<<"window">>,<<"5">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598394">>},{<<"hold">>,<<"1">>},{<<"wait">>,<<"70">>}],[],155,1,{<<"chatdomain">>,<<>>},{{127,0,0,1},50027}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:591 Actually processing request: {http_put,1598394,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"to">>,<<"chatdomain">>},{<<"window">>,<<"5">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598394">>},{<<"hold">>,<<"1">>},{<<"wait">>,<<"70">>}],[],155,1,{<<"chatdomain">>,<<>>},{{127,0,0,1},50027}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:642  -- SaveKey: 
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:654 reqlist: [{hbr,1598394,<<>>,[]}]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.176 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:700 really sending now: []
2015-12-14 16:20:19.278 [debug] <0.1241.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:900 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamstart,<<"stream:stream">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"xmlns:stream">>,<<"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">>},{<<"id">>,<<"108440446">>},{<<"from">>,<<"chatdomain">>}]}]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [info] <0.1240.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.7846>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:50028 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http:init:153 S: [{[<<"register">>],mod_register_web},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind}]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [info] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.7846>}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:280 (#Port<0.7846>) http query: 'POST' <<"/http-bind">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http:extract_path_query:392 client data: <<"<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' rid='1598395' xml:lang='en' sid='92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00'><auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=\n</auth></body>">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http:process:350 [<<"http-bind">>] matches [<<"http-bind">>]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@mod_http_bind:process:68 Incoming data: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' rid='1598395' xml:lang='en' sid='92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00'><auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=
</auth></body>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:parse_request:1114 --- incoming data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' rid='1598395' xml:lang='en' sid='92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00'><auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=
</auth></body>
 --- END --- 
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1244.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:775 Looking for session: <<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>
2015-12-14 16:20:19.279 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:442 New request: {http_put,1598395,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598395">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>}],[{xmlel,<<"auth">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">>},{<<"mechanism">>,<<"PLAIN">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=\n">>}]}],255,1,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50028}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.280 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:558 New request: {http_put,1598395,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598395">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>}],[{xmlel,<<"auth">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">>},{<<"mechanism">>,<<"PLAIN">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=\n">>}]}],255,1,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50028}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.280 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:rid_allow:852 Previous rid / New rid: 1598394/1598395
2015-12-14 16:20:19.280 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:591 Actually processing request: {http_put,1598395,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598395">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>}],[{xmlel,<<"auth">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">>},{<<"mechanism">>,<<"PLAIN">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=\n">>}]}],255,1,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50028}}
2015-12-14 16:20:19.280 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:642  -- SaveKey: 
2015-12-14 16:20:19.280 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:654 reqlist: [{hbr,1598395,<<>>,[]},{hbr,1598394,<<>>,[{xmlstreamstart,<<"stream:stream">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"xmlns:stream">>,<<"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">>},{<<"id">>,<<"108440446">>},{<<"from">>,<<"chatdomain">>}]}]}]
2015-12-14 16:20:19.280 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:700 really sending now: [{xmlel,<<"auth">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">>},{<<"mechanism">>,<<"PLAIN">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"AGFkbWluADEyMzQ=\n">>}]}]
^[OF2015-12-14 16:21:29.387 [info] <0.1240.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.7847>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:50030 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http:init:153 S: [{[<<"register">>],mod_register_web},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind}]
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [info] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.7847>}
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:280 (#Port<0.7847>) http query: 'POST' <<"/http-bind">>
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http:extract_path_query:392 client data: <<"<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' rid='1598396' xml:lang='en' sid='92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00'/>">>
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http:process:350 [<<"http-bind">>] matches [<<"http-bind">>]
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@mod_http_bind:process:68 Incoming data: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' rid='1598396' xml:lang='en' sid='92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00'/>
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:parse_request:1114 --- incoming data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' rid='1598396' xml:lang='en' sid='92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00'/>
 --- END --- 
2015-12-14 16:21:29.388 [debug] <0.1245.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:775 Looking for session: <<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:442 New request: {http_put,1598396,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598396">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>}],[],160,1,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50030}}
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:558 New request: {http_put,1598396,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598396">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>}],[],160,1,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50030}}
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:rid_allow:852 Previous rid / New rid: 1598395/1598396
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:591 Actually processing request: {http_put,1598396,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"content">>,<<"text/xml; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"1598396">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>}],[],160,1,<<>>,{{127,0,0,1},50030}}
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:642  -- SaveKey: 
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:654 reqlist: [{hbr,1598396,<<>>,[]},{hbr,1598395,<<>>,[]}]
2015-12-14 16:21:29.389 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:700 really sending now: []
2015-12-14 16:23:09.492 [info] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_info:507 Session timeout. Closing the HTTP bind session: <<"92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00">>
2015-12-14 16:23:09.492 [debug] <0.1242.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:terminate:538 terminate: Deleting session 92c4475848d8b8f10b4dbe1a66980c385f46ac00
```

Answer (score 1):

I was making a mistake in the BoshClient script.
There, in the "startSessionAndAuth" method, you can set the "wait" value, that I don't know in what stages you may want to wait but... it was set to 70 seconds by default. I set it to 0 and now is responding instantly with a new session id.

In the [protocol definition](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html#session-request) its said:

> Note: Clients that only support Polling Sessions MAY prevent the
>   connection manager from waiting by setting 'wait' or 'hold' to "0".
>   However, polling is NOT RECOMMENDED since the associated increase in
>   bandwidth consumption and the decrease in responsiveness are both
>   typically one or two orders of magnitude!

and it's exactly my case.

Comment: The complete http-bind protocol: http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html#session-request

Comment: Please, also note that with Websockets, this pre-bind matter much less, as XMPP over websocket is much speedier.

Comment: Yes, it is but we need to give support to old IE versions. :(
Good suggestion btw.